# Question regarding the definition of Local Connectedness

Tags: general-topology

In Munker's Book "Topology 2nd Edition" a Topological Space $X$ is said to be locally connected at $x\in X$ if "every neighborhood of $x$ contains a connected neighborhood of $x$".
That is given $V$ is a neighborhood of $x$ there is a connected set $U\subseteq X$ (which is not necessarily open in $X$) and a subset $W\subseteq U$ such that $W$ is open in $X$ and $x\in W\subseteq U\subseteq V$.

In wikipedia they give a different definition:
A space $X$ is said to be locally connected at $x\in X$  if for every open set $V$ containing $x$ there is a connected open set $U$ with $x\in U\subseteq V$.

The big difference is that the definition in Wikipedia assures that if $X$ is locally connected at $x$ then every neighborhood of $x\in X$ contains an **open** connected neighborhood of $x$ while the definition in the book only assures every neighborhood of $x$ contains some but not necessarily open connected neighborhood of $x$.

Obviously the Wikipedia definition implies the book's definition but I don't see whether the book's definition necessarily implies the Wikipedia definition..

Answer (score 1):

Munkres uses the term "neighborhood of x" to mean "open subset containing x" (see page 96).

Comment: Well that certainly explains it..
It's a bit irritating since that is not the common definition for neighborhood. Thanks for helping though.

Comment: @Serpahimz I am not sure I have seen anyone use the term neighborhood without meaning open neighborhood (since an arbitrary subset containing a specified element is too general a concept to be useful usually).

Comment: You're probably right about the usefulness of the "standard definition" but for some reason in most courses I've taken we've distinguished between "neighborhood" and "open neighborhoods".

Comment: @Tobias: The term *neighborhood* is often used to mean exactly what Serpahimz thought that it meant: $N$ is a nbhd of $x$ if $x$ is in the interior of $N$. This is quite different from an arbitrary set containing $x$. That’s why one speaks of open nbhds: they are an especially nice type of nbhd.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Ahh, thank you for that clarification.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: I like the way you phrased that. We should all aspire to live in an open neighborhood...

Comment: @Serpahimz: :-) (I’m fortunate: I actually do live in a pretty open nbhd.)